# Using Kubernetes with ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, kubernetes

I have a ruby on rails application running on AWS. As usual each application server have an nginx and multiple unicorn workers of the application instance.

I am going to move the workload to Kubernetes. I have couple of question regarding this, please help if anyone out there who have kubernetised there ror application.

- What will be the role of nginx?. Do i need to install nginx in all the pods or i should have a an nginx pod which will reverse proxy to all rails/unicorn pods?
- Which one is the best for ror in kubernetes, passenger or unicorn?

Answer (score 1):

**How will you use nginx?**

A kubernetes service can be backed by several kubernetes pods. Whenever anyone makes a request to the kubernetes service, the request is sent to one of the upstream pods in a round robin fashion.

If you were planning to use nginx as a 'load-balancer' or reverse proxy to front your rails app, you don't really need that anymore. Each pod ofcourse will need to have something like passenger/unicorn to serve the rails app.

Here'a a guide I found that talks about a rails deployment from start to end: http://www.thagomizer.com/blog/2015/07/01/kubernetes-and-deploying-to-google-container-engine.html

If you're planning to use nginx as a static file server, my recommendation would be to have a different pod for the static files that just contains nginx.

**What is better to use with k8s?**

K8s doesn't really care, because this is outside k8s's concern. Use whatever you like, or whatever you think works better in a container environment. The better question to ask might be *which one of passenger/unicorn is a better fit for containerised rails apps*.